# How to know that the library is compiled with no particular entries defined?

Tags: android

In the documentation of sqlite about foreign keys it is said that

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be
>   compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER
>   defined.

So how to know that SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER are defined or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I use the following in my DB helper class to initialise the database for foreign key constraint use -

```
public class DataService extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private SQLiteDatabase db;
  ..

  public void init() {
    if (db == null) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```